# Where import directory is located in meteor app file?

Tags: meteor

I'm new to meteor  and I'm learning to design [Blaze app](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates) and it says I've to write this [body.html](https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos/commit/99cffc464f80899ce34cf446179e8041c9f5114c) to import/ui/, unfortunatly I can't find that dir. Am I supposed to create one or it's a default dir generated by `meteor create stuff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meteor create` doesn't create `import/ui/`, it's up to you.

It is just recomendation, you are free to choose any structure you want, keeping in mind few specific things like loading order.

A [Meteor Guide](http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html) is a greate place to know more about application structure.